# C# template return cast можно ли кастить по возвращаемому типу?

Tags: c#

Есть web-страница. На ней набор текстовых данных Key-Value. Как можно задать ф-цию преобразования к заданному параметру? Есть хороший механизм template который сам подставляет входящий тип. Можно ли функцию описать так, чтобы возвращаемый тип сопоставлялся с декларируемым? Т.е. тип переменной слева подставился в шаблон возвращаемого типа справа? Т.е. `int id = f("id");` работало? Получаю ошибку компиляции:

> The type argumets for method f(string) can not be inferred from the
>   usage

Сама ф-ция простая, мне не нужно чтобы выдавало исключение при преобразованиях

```
Dictionary<string,object> io_data;

Т Key<T>(string id){
 if (!io_data.ContainsKey(id)) return default(T);
 try { return (T)Convert.ChangeType(io_data[key],typeof(T)); }
 catch { return default(T) }; 
}
```

Много раз везде всё кастится. Хочу сократить количество явных приведений типов.
Можно ли заставить компилятор сопоставить `Т` с типом который слева от знака `"="`: `int id = f("id");`?

Comment: >>Есть хороший механизм template<< В шарпе такого замечательного механизма, увы, нету.

Comment: >>Т.е. int id = f("id"); работало?<< Вы не даёте компилятору возможность узнать что за тип вы хотите подставить вместо T. Делайте как положено: int id = f<int>("id");, либо, ассоциируйте T с каким либо аргументом функции, чтобы компилятор понял что за T вы хотите подставить.

Comment: чем вам `var id = f<int>("id");` не нравится?

Comment: >>Т.е ни implicit не explicit ни другие подсказки (навеяло с с++) не помогут 100 раз явно не писать <int>?<< Повторюсь, у шарпа НЕТУ template. Generics ограничен, и ничего вы с этим не сделаете. Либо используйте аргумент с типом T внутри функции, либо явно указывайте <T> в вызове функции

Comment: Вот вам пример без явного <T> http://rextester.com/LBSY33044 Но, он, мягко говоря, не то что вы ожидаете. Хотите шарп - привыкайте явно использовать <T> :D

Comment: Подобный "паттерн" >>Т f<T>(string key, T value);<< использовался в яве (возможно, используется до сих пор), только, несколько более изящно, вместо T в аргументе там Class<T>, соответственно, не надо толкать реальный аргумент, достаточно сделать что то вроде f("id",Integer.class); В шарпе подобное тоже, вероятно, можно реализовать...

Comment: Тип все равно надо указывать, потому как даже мне не понятно, какой тип вы тут пытаетесь передать `int id = f("id");` - то ли int, то ли long, то ли double, то ли что то ещё, что кастится в int - а раз мне не понятно, то компилятору и подавно.

Comment: @test123: Вы так говорите, как будто синтаксис ТС можно заставить работать в C++. Нет, это не сработает и в C++, и отличия между template и generic тут вовсе не при чём.

Comment: @VladD, да, согласен, и в плюсах это тоже нельзя интерпретировать однозначно. Тут я не прав.

Comment: Аналог для с++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633477/implicit-conversion-operator-overloading-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что б кастить тип возвращаемого значение к результату можно использовать **[implicit](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit)** механизм. Но тогда нужно описать **все** возможные варианты типов которые вернёт функция. Выглядеть будет где-то так

```
Dictionary<string,object> io_data;

public class XKey {
  object v;
  public XKey(object v) { this.v = v;}
  public static implicit operator int(XKey v){ return f<int>(v.v);}
  public static implicit operator string(XKey v){ return f<string>(v.v);}

  public static T f<T>(object v){
      try{ return Convet.ChangeType(v,typeof(T));
      } catch { return default(T); }}  
  }

 public XKey f(string id){ return new XKey(io_data.ContainsKey(id)?io_data[id]:null);}

 public MyFunct() {
    int    id =   f("id");
    string name = f("name");
   }
```

Comment: Ключевое слово implicit требует что бы был оператор преобразования и туда и назад. - Разве?

Comment: Согласен, убрал.