# C++ вернуть из функции int разного размера

Tags: c++, biginteger

Нужна функция, которая будет способна возвращать как int32, так и int64. Как это наиболее грамотно реализовать?

Цель в том, чтобы вынести в функцию код, получающий из бинарного файла целые числа указанного размера по указанному эндиану.

Comment: Если беззнаковые и небоитесь "конфликтов" - union. Есть вариант template (двойственность будет), есть вариант implicit cast (создаётся обьект, который умеет кастится и к  int64 и к  int32).

Comment: Вам нужно сразу два этих значения? Если так, то можно использовать пары

Comment: Как вариант, возвращайте во всех случаях int64, но в некоторых случаях оставляйте старшую половину бит неиспользованными.

Comment: Это же не самое грамотное решение. Может, я хочу int128 или 1024

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Что значит "которая будет способна возвращать как int32, так и int64." Когда принимается решение о том, что именно надо возвращать? Во время компиляции? Во время выполнения? "Указанного размера по указанному эндиану" - когда это все указывается? Во время компиляции? Во время выполнения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Предлагаю вам вариант с template

```
 template<typename T> T getNumData(void* buff, int offs){
    T ret;
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(T);i++)  ((char*)&ret)[i] =  ((char*)buff)[i+offs];
    return ret;
      }
```

С обратным индианом аналогично но `((char*)&ret)[sizeof(T)-i-1]` 
Возможно этот вариант кривеникий, как правильно с кастами писать - не знаю.

При использовании придётся указывать желаемый тип `getNumData<int32>(q,0)` это вам позволит сразу декодировать все 3-4 варианта от 8бит до 64.

Если ф-цию `getNumData` переделать на такую  `template<typename T> void getNumData(T& ret, void* data, int offs)` тогда не придётся указывать `<int32>` - можно будет записать `getNumData(retvar,q,0);`
Вариант достаточно хороший по быстродействию.

Еще есть варианты:

- Вернуть union (просто, но будет а) потеря знака б) невозможно для обратного indian.
- Вернуть int64 и кастить (невозможно для обратного indian)
- Вернуть класс, и прописать правила каста к каждому из типов (больше кода, удобно, но можно запутаться) - implicit cast.

---

Вариант 2. От лишних `<>` можно избавится "жертвуя" дополнительным классом (некоторые компиляторы съедят `struct`, но всётаки операторы относятся к классам `class`). Покажу implicit cast - так это называется, т.е. компилятор смотрит к какому классу идёт каст, и делает вызов определенного оператора. Нужно этот метод проверять дизассемблером, что б компилятор вызовы new и delete не лепил. Для одной переменной компилятор не создаёт конструкторы деструкторы. При использовании могут быть потери скорости, поэтому лучше проверить. В упрощённой схеме получится так:

```
class /*struct*/ autocast {              
    public:
    void *data; 
     // кастим к int32, в комментарии вариант для обратного indian
    operator int32() {  return  *(int32*)data; /*return getData<int>(data,0)*/ } 
    // кастим к int64
    operator int64() {  return  *(int64*)data; }
    };
//И можно запилить 
    autocast /*inline*/ getNumDataVar(void* data){ /*Дописать offs*/
        autocast ret;
        ret.data = data;
        return ret;
      }
// вызов делается так (но тип слева должен быть одним из тех,
// для которого существует оператор implicit cast) 
int32 query =  getNumDataVar(q);
```

Недостаток - вместо одного вызова - будет два вызова (некоторые компиляторы могут сделать 4-ре, но указанием `inline` может быть скомпилирован как один вызов так и ноль, зависит от компилятора), зато удобнее в использовании. Недостаток - больше кода - для каждого типа прийдётся писать отдельный каст, в отличии от первого варианта, но иногда такое разделение позволяет добавить быстродействие (легче избавится от циклов и т п).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, точно. для 32 sizeof=4, 4-3 = 1 а не 0.

Comment: Вот с шаблонами <тип> хорошо

Comment: Я долго искал решение можно ли сделать y=f(x) что б не указывать  <тип>. Оно существует, и почему-то до сих пор нигде не описано в таком варианте. Думаю... последний вариант понравится если надоест писать <тип>. На с# я это задействовал в одном из проэктов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797470/c-template-return-cast-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%83/797576#797576.

Comment: Надо быстрее по выполнению, так что вроде лучше без классов для инта

Comment: Кому важно быстродействие - те применяют template, и в некоторых случаях циклы можно заменить на #define. Быстродействие - такая спорная тема... кстати... второй метод позволяет убрать циклы (с template убрать циклы - сложнее). Кроме того getNumDataVar обьявленная как inline - новые компиляторы её заинлайнят в код - и будет один вызов. А в "вариации" можно сделать ассемблерные вставки... и второй код тогда может работать быстрее первого (пока что теоретически).  Я считаю что спрашивающие должны знать разные варианты реализации (рабочие). Я не думаю что ответ нужно делить на 2 разных ответа.

Answer (score 2):

В C++ нельзя перегружать функции по возвращаемому значению. Иными словами следующая перегрузка неправльна

```
int32 getInt();
int64 getInt();
```

Но есть другие способы:

1. Сделать две разные функции и вызывать необходимую:

   ```
   int32 getInt32();
   int64 getInt64();
   ```

   Можно сделать эту функцию шаблонной но это особо ничего не изменит.
2. Не возвращать значение вообще. Передавать указатель или ссылки на обеъкты:

   ```
   void getInt(int32&, int64&);
   ```
3. Возвращать структуру из пары элементов

   ```
   struct UniversalInt {
      int32 i32;
      int64 i64;
   };
   UniversalInt getInt();
   ```

   Но тут вознкают проблемы: во-первых не зависимо от резульата память будет выделена под оба элемента, а использован один, а во-вторых неизвестно какой тип именно был возвращен.
4. Использовать `union`. Это частично решит проблему с выделением лишней памяти. Этот вариант не стоит использовать в такой реализации вообще.

   ```
    union UniversalInt {
      int32 i32;
      int64 i64;
    };
    UniversalInt getInt();
   ```
5. К `union` добавить информацию о возвращенном типе. Хорошая новость заключатся в том, что такая структура уже есть - [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant); плохая новость заключается в том, что добавлен `std::variant` был только в С++17.

   ```
    std::variant<int32, int64> getInt();
   ```

   Как вариант можно использовать [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html).
   Для POD типов подобная структура будет довольно просто выглядеть и её можно написать самостоятельно.
   Как только оказывается, что подходит `variant` имеет смысл задуматься об использовании шаблона [посетитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

На мой взгляд лучшим вариантом будет первый.

Comment: Шаблонная как минимум избавит от дублирования кода для n функций.